# Local node js app as standalone node_module

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

Having multiple in-house local node js apps, for modularity purposes, we would like that the apps use each other as node_modules instead of having all the apps under one source control.

For example

If I have 3 local apps; app_main, app_2 and app_3, to be able in app_main folder to do something as follows

```
app_main> npm install app_2 --save
```

Instead of having the folder

```
app_main/apps/app_x
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few options available:

```
npm install [PATH/TO/APP]
  // this pulls only the current version of the app into the node_modules dependancies. 

npm link [PATH/TO/APP] 
  // this sets up symlinks to the local package and propagates changes from dependancies

npm install git+ssh://[GIT@REPO] 
  // this is pretty easy if you have a git repo besides npm that your package is kept
```

Answer (score 1):

npm accepts a path as well. So if you put all your modules in a central (maybe version controlled) location you could install them with `npm install --save /path/to/your/module`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sinopia`, which is a private npm repository.

https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind paying and you are using a more recent version of npm, you can create private modules on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules